# Differential equation about normals

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

Solving this question and explain please help me

The curve for which the normal at any point $(x,y)$ and line joining origin to that point form an isosceles with the $x$ axis as base ,is

1. an ellipse
2. a rectangular hyperbola
3. a circle
4. none of these

Comment: You are more likely to get help here if you edit the question to show what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I have not understand this question please solve it

Comment: To understand it, proceed in the reverse and next try to write the suitable equations. So is, draw an isosceles triangle with the base on the x-axis and a vertex on the origin, then, the third vertex, that out of the x axis, belong to the curve you are searching for. From here, distances are an important thing to consider.

Comment: Which part of the question do you not understand? If there are any words you do not know, you should look them up in your textbook.

Answer (score 1):

That won't do you any good- to understand it, you need to make the effort yourself.  Can we, at least, assume you know what "normal to  a curve" and "isosceles triangle" **mean**?  Do you know what an "ellipse", "rectangular hyperbola", and "circle" are?

Suppose the curve is given by y= f(x).  The "normal" to the curve at $(x_0, f(x_0)$ is $y= -\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}(x- x_0)+ f(x_0)$.  That line will cross the x-axis when y= 0: at (x, 0) where x satisfies $-\frac{1}{f'(x_0)}(x- x_0)+ f(x_0)= 0$.  You should easily be able to solve that for x.  This will form an isosceles triangle if the two sides are of equal length.  One side, from (0, 0) to $(x_0, f(x_0)$, has length $\sqrt{x_0^2+ f(x_0)^2}$.  The other, from $(x_0, f(x_0))$ to (x, 0) (x being the solution to the equation above) has length $\sqrt{(x- x_0)^2+ f(x_0)^2}$.  Set those equal and solve for $f(x)$.

Comment: Thank you  sir for solving this i understand after read